# Collapse a div until certain point with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to collapse a div when the user scrolls down the page.

when the user loads the page the div has a 500px height, when he scrolls, the div is dinamically reducing his height to until reach 200px, then the div does not reduces  height anymore,keeps stucked in top of the page and the other contents of the page flows below this div.

Sorry for my english, mi native language is spanish.

thanks very much!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kuxafolulu/edit?html,output @Mohamed-Yousef thanks for awnser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use `.css()`**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
     var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     if(windowTop > 500){
         $('.header').css({'position':'fixed','height': '200px'});
     }else{
         $('.header').css({'position':'relative','height': '500px'});
     }
   });
});
```

```css
html,body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.content{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
 <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

**You can also use add/removeClass with transition-duration in css**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
     var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     if(windowTop > 500){
         $('.header').addClass('scrolled');
     }else{
         $('.header').removeClass('scrolled');
     }
   });
});
```

```css
html,body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.content{
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
    transition-duration : 1s;
}

.header.scrolled{
  position : fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height : 200px;
  transition-duration : 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
 <h1>Heading</h1>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```